# how to increase container width to fix GridView scroll in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, cgridview

I am using yii2 GridView widget for showing data in form of table.

As there are many fields to show, GridView ( below table ) showing scroll for it. But i don't want it.

I want to increase container width so that it show table without scroll.

I had search about bootstrap.css file but not found in any directory.

How do i change GridView width ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
      .........
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    'tableOptions' =>['style' => 'width: 1800px;'],
    ]); ?>
```

or the gridview container options

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
      .........
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    'options' =>['style' => 'width: 1800px;'],
    ]); ?>
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$options-detail

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-gridview.html#$tableOptions-detail

Otherwise if you need  a larger page container  you need  a new layout

add  tye new layout in  you app/views/layout  eg:changing  the container  this this way

```
    ....
    <div class="container-fluid">    
    <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
        'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
    ]) ?>
    <?= Alert::widget() ?>
    <?= $content ?>
    </div>
    ....
```

then assign you new layout to you view before render

```
    public function actionIndex()
    {


        ......

        $this->layout = 'my_new_layout'
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: `'options' =>['style' => 'width: 1800px;'],` this increase table width ( with the scroll )which is alredy set to width: 100%. I want to increase container width so that i can utilise space and show table without scroll

Comment: You mean that you need  a larger  page container ?